# How to fill completion type field in elasticsearch from another field of same type for existing documents

Tags: elasticsearch

I want to add a particular field of type **completion** in an existing index having documents already !!

I used this query :

```
PUT test_index/_mapping/locations 
{
  "properties": {
    "location_name_suggest": {
     "type": "completion",
     "payloads" : false      
    }
  }
}
```

Then I inserted 2-3 documents and used the **completion suggester** query

```
POST test_index/_suggest
{
"suggestions": {
  "text": "ch",
  "completion": {
     "field": "location_name_suggest"
    }
  }
}
```

There is an existing field named **location_name** in my index, how can i copy **location_name** to **location_name_suggest** without deleting the index ??

Comment: Did you find any solution?